# How to output COA_INT in fluid template form element

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I'd like to pass an extension GP variable to a form that I built outside of the plugin. When trying to do so, I used a COA_INT which turned out to output `<INT_SCRIPT.` instead of the value.

In order to do so, I built this typoscript object:

```
lib.gpSWord = COA_INT
lib.gpSWord {
    # Protects from XSS!
    stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        stdWrap.data = GP:tx_indexedsearch_pi2|search|sword
    }
}
```

and then tried to output it like this (as suggested [here](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/37988#note-9):

```
<f:form.textfield name="search[sword]" value="<f:format.raw>{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.gpSWord')}</f:format.raw>" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" class="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword font-h2" />
```

And also tried building up the variable before hand using `f:variable` but nothing worked.

The expected result would be that the variable would be set and the value would then be passed to the form.textfield viewhelper but appearently this does'nt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should commit the variable in Typoscript (setup) with:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.variables.gpSWord < lib.gpSWord
```

Then you are able to use it in you Fluidtemplate with:

```
<f:format.raw>{gpSWord}</f:format.raw>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as ading `<f:variable name="gpSword"><f:format.raw>{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.gpSWord')}</f:format.raw></f:variable>`

Comment: I alway use my recommended way and it works like a charm. I also used this in the Fluidtemplate: <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.gpSWord"/> that also worked. But I recommend the one in my answer because it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
lib.gpSWord = COA_INT
lib.gpSWord {    
  stdWrap {
      wrap = &tx_indexedsearch_pi2[sword]=|
      data = GP:tx_indexedsearch_pi2|sword
      if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_indexedsearch_pi2|sword
    }
}
```

Try this for GP.